# Java JTextField and JLabel save method

Tags: java, forms, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

I have an class which act like a form for the user.
I have a lot of field and I want to apply a particulary method from my model for each textfield content.
Which listener I need to use ? How can I get the label content of the textfield which have fire the event ?

```
public class Formulaire extends JPanel {

Boolean edited = false;

public Formulaire(String[] labels, String[] content) {
    this.setLayout(new SpringLayout());
    int numPairs = labels.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < numPairs; i++) {
        JLabel l = new JLabel(labels[i], JLabel.TRAILING);
        this.add(l);
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.setText(content[i]);
        l.setLabelFor(textField);
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(dcListener);
        this.add(textField);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post pertinent code here with your question and not as a link. Links can go bad over time making your question unhelpful to future visitors. Also, we greatly appreciate it if you make it as easy as possible for us to help you. Also if you have too much code to post on this site, then you likely have too much code to ask a volunteer to go through.

Comment: It would depend on when and what you want to add to the model. You could use a `InputVerifier`, `FocusListener` and/or `ActionListener`...

Comment: I have use DocumentListener and override the method insertUpdate and removeUpdate to change a boolean "edited" to true. I only want to apply method from the model and the end of editing all forms and the user clic on my save button. That's why I need to know what is the label name of the edited field.

Comment: Damn i can't upload an image... http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/357640button.png